# DBIx::Class Find or Create objects

Tags: perl, dbix-class

I'm using DBIx::Class to model the following:

A `Recipe` with many `Tags`. The `Tag` is shared with other `Recipe` objects.

While creating a `Recipe` object I want to create a set of `Tag` objects and associate them with the newly created `Recipe` object. (The user enters a list of tags and I only have the name of the tag to go with)

For the Tags I could iterate over the list and find one that matches the user entered name or create a new object manually.

I couldn't find a documented `findOrCreate` type method in DBIx::Class. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a key on the name you can use [find_or_create](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class::ResultSet#find_or_create).

Comment: How do you know whether the object was 'found' or 'created'?                       $obj = $schema->resultset('ObjList')->find_or_create({...some conditions...});

Comment: Please read the documentation. Here is what it says: If you need to know if an existing row was found or a new one created use "find_or_new" and "in_storage" in DBIx::Class::Row instead. Don't forget to call "insert" in DBIx::Class::Row to save the newly created row to the database!